# Updating jquery el.val() in angular form directive doesn't update $viewValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive that modifies an input within an ng-form.  However, whenever I change the value of the field (using .val()), the $viewValue stays the same, which throws off my validation.

Any idea how I can fix that?

```
          .directive('kcAutotab',function kcAutotab() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el.on('keyup', function (e) {
                //don't autotab if the key pressed was left or right arrow, tab, or shift
                if ((e.keyCode !== 37 && e.keyCode !== 39 && e.keyCode !== 9&& e.keyCode !== 16 && e.keyCode !== 8)) {
                    if (el.val().length >= parseInt(el.attr('maxlength'))) {
                        //el.val(el.val().substr(0, parseInt(el.attr('maxlength'))));
                        attrs['ngModel'] = el.val().substr(0, parseInt(el.attr('maxlength')));
                        $('#' + attrs['kcAutotab']).focus();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

That's my directive, and you  can see where I'm doing `el.val(el.val().substr(0, parseInt(el.attr('maxlength'))));` to set the value.  However whenever I analyze the form (either by printing the entire form to the client or by checking it with ng-inspector), $viewValue is whatever the el.val() was before I manipulated it.

EDIT:  Updated the directive per suggestion

Comment: Why are you updating the dom value rather than the model that the template is rendering?

Comment: That's... a great idea.  How do I go about doing that though?  The directive isn't inheriting any model from the template, right?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, check my update.  It isn't quite working for me but I think we're on the right track.

Comment: You could try and wrap the update in $scope.$apply